# Debugging a Metropolis Hastings Algorithm Simulation

Tags: probability, monte-carlo, simulation

I have some questions about the Metropolis Hastings algorithm:

Wikipedia says:

> ...choose an arbitrary probability density g(x|y) which suggests a
>   candidate for the next sample value x, given the previous sample value
>   y....A usual choice is to let g(x|y) be a Gaussian distribution
>   centered at y,

I tried using this (in R):

```
xdash=x+rnorm(1,mean=0,sd=0.1)
```

where `x, xdash` are the latest & proposed point respectively.

Suppose my function `f(x)` which I'm trying to sample is defined only on `0<= x <= 1` what do I do at the edges when the proposed point is say outside the domain? Do I just reject & draw another point from the gaussian?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metropolis%E2%80%93Hastings_algorithm

Reason I ask is I'm getting strange sampling at the edges.

[image]

f(x) was defined so:

[image]

```
fn<-function(x){
  if (x<=0.4 && x>=0){
    return ( 5  )
  } else if (x>0.4 && x<=0.6) {
    return (10)
  } else if (x>0.6 && x<=1) {
    return(5)
  }
  else {
    return (0)
  }
}
```

Here's my code:

```
x= runif(1,min=0,max=1)
max_iter=10000
sd=0.1;
accepts<-c()

for(i in 1:max_iter){
  xdash=x+rnorm(1,mean=0,sd=sd)

  if(fn(x)==0) {
    alpha<-0
  } else {
    alpha <- fn(xdash)/fn(x)
  }

  if (runif(n=1,min=0,max=1)<alpha) {
    #accept
    accepts<-c(accepts,xdash)
    x<-xdash
  } 
}
```

Edited Code:

```
x= runif(1,min=0,max=1)
max_iter=10000; sd=0.1;
samples<-c()

for(i in 1:max_iter){
  xdash=x+rnorm(1,mean=0,sd=sd)
  alpha <- fn(xdash)/fn(x)
  if (runif(n=1,min=0,max=1)<alpha) {
    x<-xdash
  } 
  samples<-c(samples,x)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by "reject & draw another point from the Gaussian".

Just extend $f$ to all of $\mathbb R$, with $f(x)=0$ outside $[0,1]$, and sample from that density. In the code you posted, you already did that. Then apply the standard algorithm. If by "reject & draw another point from the Gaussian" you mean that you immediately try again without counting the point at which you stayed because of the rejection as another sample, that would violate detailed balance and would lead to underrepresentation of the points near the boundary. That's not what the standard algorithm prescribes for the function defined in your code.

Your second question is unrelated and hard to answer independent of circumstances; I'd suggest to post it as a separate question, perhaps with some background on what sort of scenario you need this for (assuming that the simple example you provided here isn't the distribution you're actually intending to simulate in practice).

Comment: Thanks! I'v edited out my follow up question & also added my full code. So, if what I'm doing seems OK, any idea why my sample generated doesn't seem exactly right. It seems to have this distinct fall near the edges of the domain?

Comment: Also, with f(x) set to zero outside of [0,1] there's the risk of a division by zero when calculating the acceptance probability alpha. What's the correct way to handle this condition.

Comment: @curious_cat: No, you're making exactly the mistake I thought you were. You're accepting a sample only when you've moved. That will give you a wrong distribution quite independent of these domain issues. You need to accept all values, regardless of whether the move was accepted or rejected. (In the Wikipedia article, this is the part "if the candidate is rejected, set $x_{t+1} = x_t$, instead.")

Comment: @curious_cat: There are no division-by-zero problems because you never accept a candidate for which the density is zero, and you only ever divide by the density for samples that you've accepted.

Comment: Wow. Thanks. I think I fundamentally had misunderstood the algorithm (probably because I still view it intuitively & haven't mastered the underlying theory) But it seems now that "accept" & "reject" pertain to the moves. I had misunderstood them as pertaining to the acceptance / rejection of the samples themselves!

Comment: I've posted corrected code. Does this seem right? Thanks a lot for correcting my understanding!

Comment: @curious_cat: Yes, the code looks right now, and your insight that "accept" and "reject" pertain to the moves and not the samples is also exactly right. About intuition and theory: Ideally you can master the theory to the point where its results appear intuitive ;-)

Comment: In hindsight, a part of my confusion came from Rejection Sampling. There "accept" and "reject" are used in the sense of whether to add a point to the sample or not. Here they refer to the move alone not on the decision of whether to add a point to the sample.